# Android 2.2: diminished reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am planning to develop an diminished reality application for Android phone. If theres any existing `frameworks`, that is. Could anyone tell me where to start? Thanks

Comment: What the hell is a diminished reality app?

Comment: Your question is too vague.  What do you mean by diminished reality?  What exactly would you be hoping that such a framework would provide?

Comment: Diminished reality is removing objects from an image in real time.

Comment: Heres an example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgTq-AgYlTE @CommonsWare, Nothing, yet. I wanted to know if anyone of you have done something similar.

Answer (score 0):

To get started I would recommend to download the Android [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), get the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AndroidExperimental) framework and read the paper from the people who did the video demo [Paper from TU Ilmenau (PDF)](http://www.tu-ilmenau.de/fileadmin/public/vwds/publications/Advanced%20Self-contained%20Object%20Removal%20for%20Realizing%20Rea.pdf). Sounds like a fun project.